# The results are not as i desired using foreach loop

Tags: php, sql, join

```php
$warehousesArray = array(
    'Paharganj' => '5',
    'Sant Nagar' => '11324',
    'Mumbai' => '35798',
    'UP Border' => '117262',
    'Top Floor' => '170740',
    'Gurgaon' => '170741'
);


$stockSummaryQuery1 = "SELECT
        p.productid,
        p.productname,
        scf.cf_976 AS stock_quantity,
        w.warehousename,
        SUM(IF(scf.cf_974=scf.cf_976 AND scf.cf_974 != 0,1,0)) AS number_of_packs
    FROM vtiger_products AS p
    LEFT JOIN vtiger_productcf AS pcf ON pcf.productid = p.productid
    LEFT JOIN vtiger_stockscf AS scf ON scf.cf_922 = p.productid
    LEFT JOIN vtiger_stocks AS s ON scf.stocksid = s.stocksid
    JOIN vtiger_crmentity AS stockent ON stockent.crmid = s.stocksid AND stockent.deleted = 0
    LEFT JOIN vtiger_racks AS ra ON ra.racksid = scf.cf_924
    JOIN vtiger_rackscf AS racf ON ra.racksid = racf.racksid
    JOIN vtiger_rooms AS ro ON ro.roomsid = racf.cf_900
    JOIN vtiger_roomscf AS rocf ON rocf.roomsid = ro.roomsid
    JOIN vtiger_warehouses AS w ON rocf.cf_910 = w.warehousesid
    LEFT JOIN vtiger_vendor AS v ON v.vendorid = p.vendor_id 
    WHERE 1";

if (isset($_GET['vendor_name']) && !empty($_GET['vendor_name'])) {
    $warehouseid_array = explode("_", $_GET['vendor_name']);
    $warehouseid = $warehouseid_array[0];
    $stockSummaryQuery1 .= " AND v.vendorid = " . $warehouseid;
}

foreach ($warehousesArray as $key => $value) {
    echo  $stockSummaryQuery1 .= " AND w.warehousesid = $value";
    echo "<br><br><br><br>";
}

$stockSummaryQuery1 .= " GROUP BY p.productid ASC";
```

I have echoed the queries and the result is:

```sql
SELECT p.productid, p.productname, scf.cf_976 AS stock_quantity, w.warehousename, SUM(IF(scf.cf_974=scf.cf_976 AND scf.cf_974 != 0,1,0)) AS number_of_packs FROM vtiger_products AS p LEFT JOIN vtiger_productcf AS pcf ON pcf.productid = p.productid LEFT JOIN vtiger_stockscf AS scf ON scf.cf_922 = p.productid LEFT JOIN vtiger_stocks AS s ON scf.stocksid = s.stocksid JOIN vtiger_crmentity AS stockent ON stockent.crmid = s.stocksid AND stockent.deleted = 0 LEFT JOIN vtiger_racks AS ra ON ra.racksid = scf.cf_924 JOIN vtiger_rackscf AS racf ON ra.racksid = racf.racksid JOIN vtiger_rooms AS ro ON ro.roomsid = racf.cf_900 JOIN vtiger_roomscf AS rocf ON rocf.roomsid = ro.roomsid JOIN vtiger_warehouses AS w ON rocf.cf_910 = w.warehousesid LEFT JOIN vtiger_vendor AS v ON v.vendorid = p.vendor_id WHERE 1 AND w.warehousesid = 5
```

```sql
SELECT p.productid, p.productname, scf.cf_976 AS stock_quantity, w.warehousename, SUM(IF(scf.cf_974=scf.cf_976 AND scf.cf_974 != 0,1,0)) AS number_of_packs FROM vtiger_products AS p LEFT JOIN vtiger_productcf AS pcf ON pcf.productid = p.productid LEFT JOIN vtiger_stockscf AS scf ON scf.cf_922 = p.productid LEFT JOIN vtiger_stocks AS s ON scf.stocksid = s.stocksid JOIN vtiger_crmentity AS stockent ON stockent.crmid = s.stocksid AND stockent.deleted = 0 LEFT JOIN vtiger_racks AS ra ON ra.racksid = scf.cf_924 JOIN vtiger_rackscf AS racf ON ra.racksid = racf.racksid JOIN vtiger_rooms AS ro ON ro.roomsid = racf.cf_900 JOIN vtiger_roomscf AS rocf ON rocf.roomsid = ro.roomsid JOIN vtiger_warehouses AS w ON rocf.cf_910 = w.warehousesid LEFT JOIN vtiger_vendor AS v ON v.vendorid = p.vendor_id WHERE 1 AND w.warehousesid = 5 AND w.warehousesid = 11324
```

```sql
SELECT p.productid, p.productname, scf.cf_976 AS stock_quantity, w.warehousename, SUM(IF(scf.cf_974=scf.cf_976 AND scf.cf_974 != 0,1,0)) AS number_of_packs FROM vtiger_products AS p LEFT JOIN vtiger_productcf AS pcf ON pcf.productid = p.productid LEFT JOIN vtiger_stockscf AS scf ON scf.cf_922 = p.productid LEFT JOIN vtiger_stocks AS s ON scf.stocksid = s.stocksid JOIN vtiger_crmentity AS stockent ON stockent.crmid = s.stocksid AND stockent.deleted = 0 LEFT JOIN vtiger_racks AS ra ON ra.racksid = scf.cf_924 JOIN vtiger_rackscf AS racf ON ra.racksid = racf.racksid JOIN vtiger_rooms AS ro ON ro.roomsid = racf.cf_900 JOIN vtiger_roomscf AS rocf ON rocf.roomsid = ro.roomsid JOIN vtiger_warehouses AS w ON rocf.cf_910 = w.warehousesid LEFT JOIN vtiger_vendor AS v ON v.vendorid = p.vendor_id WHERE 1 AND w.warehousesid = 5 AND w.warehousesid = 11324 AND w.warehousesid = 35798
```

My desired result is the `warehouseid` is only written once and the values changes from `5` to `11324` and then `35798`.

Comment: mb you should use `OR` instead of `AND` in the `WHERE` section
`WHERE 1 AND (w.warehousesid = 5 OR w.warehousesid = 11324 OR w.warehousesid = 35798`)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide a relevant and minimal sample data showcasing your requirements, and expected output. Please go through this link once: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)